# How to move files inDolphin using right-click menu

Tags: mouse, dolphin

I want to move a group of files in Dolphin using the right-click menu.  I can copy them, delete them, or rename them.  But I don't see any way to simply move them.  I know I can drag and drop them, but my mouse is a bit touchy so I'd rather not move them that way. I expected to find this functionality in the right click menu, but it doesn't seem to be there. I don't want to copy them. (I'm running Kubuntu 20.04.)

Comment: If you don't want to copy, then use `cut` (in the right-click menu) or Crtl+x (keybooard).

Comment: Doesn't cut and paste involve actually moving data? I want to achieve the effect of the mv command for a group of files, and mv doesn't move data.